# Proper way to import JSLib into k6.io tests

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, k6

I tried to follow guide of k6.io to import JS modules in the test:

https://jslib.k6.io/

[image]

My js tests can't load:

import { uuidv4 } from "https://jslib.k6.io/k6-utils/1.4.0/index.j"

```
//@ts-check
import http from "k6/http";
import { check } from "k6";
import { Counter } from "k6/metrics";
import { jsonRequest } from "../data/createNode.js";
import { uuidv4 } from "https://jslib.k6.io/k6-utils/1.4.0/index.j"


//counter for http codes
var http200 = new Counter("HTTP_200_counter")
var error400 = new Counter("HTTP_400_error_counter")
var error500 = new Counter("HTTP_500_error_counter")
```

[image]

**---------------- UPDATE 20 JUL -----------------**

[image]

[image]

Comment: This should work. Does `k6 run createNodeTests.js` not work? Note that your code block contains `index.j` (instead of `index.js`).

Comment: And indeed, if I copy paste your code, remove the `import { jsonRequest }` (I don't have the file), add a default function which logs `uuidv4()` and execute it with `k6 run myfile.js`, everything works as expected: the remote lib is imported, the default function runs, the uuid is generated.

Comment: @knittl Hello, I'm sorry for delay. I've update my question with the latest attempt: VSCode highlighted that it can't find the module. I've executed script and uuid4 was not recognized

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). It makes it a lot easier to copy & paste your code and ultimately help you. `uuidv4` is recognized as can be seen by your output. But you are not invoking the function, you are logging the function definition. To invoke a function, you need to add parentheses `uuidv4()` (which is exactly what I wrote in my previous comment).

Comment: My bad, I'm sorry, missed the fact the it was undoubtedly FUNCTION, not it is good INFO[0000] UUID: dc92fccb-c98c-4374-b49d-adc9b0ba0ffd ------------  source=console